# view loads to black screen iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am loading a view up with a uinavigationcontroller like this:

```
var tagController = TagPlaceController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tagController, animated: true)
```

The problem is it just loads a black screen but I know it is loading the nib and view because I put println in there. This is my load view method

```
override func loadView() {
    println("loadview")
    NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("TagPlaceView", owner: self, options: nil)
}
```

and this is my viewdidload method

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    println("viewdidload")
}
```

in the xib file I have the file's owner set to the TagPlaceController
What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loadNibNamed:owner:options: returns an array, but you haven't done anything with the returned value. You need to get the first item of that array, and assign self.view to it.

Comment: this loaded the view but now none of my outlets work... this is odd because I didn't have to do this in any other view controller

Comment: @TylerRice, why are you using a xib instead of the storyboard? Unless you have a good reason, like using this view in multiple places in your app, you should be using storyboards.

Comment: this is legacy code and the app wasn't originally done in storyboard. Also I figured this out already but thanks for the help!